# How to clip contours inside of shape file using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm doing a kernel density plot but my contours are extending out into areas of water. I don't have much experience with coding, but I used a shape file to plot my "base map". However, I'm not sure how to go about creating a clip path from my shape file so that the contours are cut against the edges of the country. Any guidance on this issue would be really appreciated.

I decided to create a clip path using the outer boundaries of my shapefile.
However, when I applied the set_clip_path function to my contour collections, the inside of the polygon boundaries was clipped instead.
Here is the gist of the code I used.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import shapefile as shp

lon_lat_box = (-61.979370, -60.444031, 9.974261, 11.375031)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

Path = mpath.Path

#read shape file
sfile = shp.Reader("./tto_adm0/TTO_adm0.shp")

#make clip path
for shape_rec in sfile.shapeRecords():
    vertices = []
    codes = []
    pts = shape_rec.shape.points
    prt = list(shape_rec.shape.parts) + [len(pts)]
    for i in range(len(prt) - 1):
        for j in range(prt[i], prt[i+1]):
            vertices.append((pts[j][0], pts[j][1]))
        codes += [Path.MOVETO]
        codes += [Path.LINETO] * (prt[i+1] - prt[i] -2)
        codes += [Path.CLOSEPOLY]
    clip = mpath.Path(vertices, codes)
    clip = mpatches.PathPatch(clip, facecolor = 'white')

#plot    
ax1.add_patch(clip)
plt.xlim(lon_lat_box[0],lon_lat_box[1])
plt.ylim(lon_lat_box[2],lon_lat_box[3])

plot_map(shape_ex)
ax1.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cut, cmap="jet", alpha=0.3)
contour = ax1.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cut, cmap="jet", alpha=0.3)
C = plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cut, cmap="jet", alpha=0.3)
plt.colorbar(C)
for c in contour.collections:
    c.set_clip_path(clip)    

fig.savefig(pdf_name)
fig.show()
```

[Here is what the output looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEW4p.png)

Update:
I realized that the line "ax1.add_patch(clip)" just masks all of the contour fill inside of the country boundaries, since I set the face color to white. 
This means that the contours are still not being clipped using my patch created, and I don't know why.

The result if I removed the "ax1.add_patch(clip)" line looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQBco.png)

Update 2:
With  ImportanceOfBeingErnest's suggestion, I was able to resolve my issue and obtain [the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xqUX.png)
The following adjustments to my code were made:

```
contour = ax1.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cut, cmap="jet", alpha=0.3)
plt.colorbar(contour)
for c in contour.collections:
c.set_clip_path(clip)
```

Comment: You have 3 times the same contour, but only one of them gets clipped. Also making the patch white will surely not help in seeing anything behind it. Apart, the code is no [mcve], so one cannot test possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it now!

Comment: You never defined the `cut` variable in the script. I'm guessing that's supposed to be the number of contour levels?